# Multiple functions in a single tapply or aggregate statement

Tags: r, aggregate, tapply

Is it possible to include two functions within a single tapply or aggregate statement?

Below I use two tapply statements and two aggregate statements: one for mean and one for SD.
I would prefer to combine the statements.

```
my.Data = read.table(text = "
  animal    age     sex  weight
       1  adult  female     100
       2  young    male      75
       3  adult    male      90
       4  adult  female      95
       5  young  female      80
", sep = "", header = TRUE)

with(my.Data, tapply(weight, list(age, sex), function(x) {mean(x)}))
with(my.Data, tapply(weight, list(age, sex), function(x) {sd(x)  }))

with(my.Data, aggregate(weight ~ age + sex, FUN = mean)
with(my.Data, aggregate(weight ~ age + sex, FUN =   sd)

# this does not work:

with(my.Data, tapply(weight, list(age, sex), function(x) {mean(x) ; sd(x)}))

# I would also prefer that the output be formatted something similar to that 
# show below.  `aggregate` formats the output perfectly.  I just cannot figure 
# out how to implement two functions in one statement.

  age    sex   mean        sd
adult female   97.5  3.535534
adult   male     90        NA
young female   80.0        NA
young   male     75        NA
```

I can always run two separate statements and merge the output.  I was just hoping there might be
a slightly more convenient solution.

I found the answer below posted here: [Apply multiple functions to column using tapply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406461/apply-multiple-functions-to-column-using-tapply)

```
f <- function(x) c(mean(x), sd(x))
do.call( rbind, with(my.Data, tapply(weight, list(age, sex), f)) )
```

However, neither the rows or columns are labeled.

```
     [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 97.5 3.535534
[2,] 80.0       NA
[3,] 90.0       NA
[4,] 75.0       NA
```

I would prefer a solution in base R.  A solution from the `plyr` package was posted at the link above.  If I can add the correct row and column headings to the above output, it would be perfect.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

But these should have:

```
with(my.Data, aggregate(weight, list(age, sex), function(x) { c(MEAN=mean(x), SD=sd(x) )}))

with(my.Data, tapply(weight, list(age, sex), function(x) { c(mean(x) , sd(x) )} ))
# Not a nice structure but the results are in there

with(my.Data, aggregate(weight ~ age + sex, FUN =  function(x) c( SD = sd(x), MN= mean(x) ) ) )
    age    sex weight.SD weight.MN
1 adult female  3.535534 97.500000
2 young female        NA 80.000000
3 adult   male        NA 90.000000
4 young   male        NA 75.
```

The principle to be adhered to is to have your function return "one thing" which could be either a vector or a list but cannot be the successive invocation of two function calls.

Comment: Thank you!  The two aggregate statements work.  The tapply statement does not appear to work, but I can use the aggregate approach.

Comment: Well I think it "works", just not to give you something that prints nicely. Try `with(my.Data, tapply(weight, list(age, sex), function(x) { c(mean(x) , sd(x) )} ))[1,1]` and play around with the indices  to see inside that matrix of lists.

Comment: I see.  Thank you.  And if I put the entire statement inside colnames() or rownames() then I get the labels.

Comment: The result here is a matrix as a column in a data frame for the third column. Easily solved by wrapping the whole thing in a `do.call(data.frame, ...)`. +1

Comment: Or even `do.call(rbind, ...)` as is often effective with the results of `by(...)` operations.

Answer (score 10):

If you'd like to use data.table, it has `with` and `by` built right into it:

```
library(data.table)
myDT <- data.table(my.Data, key="animal")


myDT[, c("mean", "sd") := list(mean(weight), sd(weight)), by=list(age, sex)]


myDT[, list(mean_Aggr=sum(mean(weight)), sd_Aggr=sum(sd(weight))), by=list(age, sex)]
     age    sex mean_Aggr   sd_Aggr
1: adult female     96.0  3.6055513
2: young   male     76.5  2.1213203
3: adult   male     91.0  1.4142136
4: young female     84.5  0.7071068
```

*I used a slightly different data set so as to not have `NA` values for sd*

Answer (score 7):

In the spirit of sharing, *if you are familiar with SQL*, you might also consider the "sqldf" package. (Emphasis added because you do need to know, for instance, that `mean` is `avg` in order to get the results you want.)

```
sqldf("select age, sex, 
      avg(weight) `Wt.Mean`, 
      stdev(weight) `Wt.SD` 
      from `my.Data` 
      group by age, sex")
    age    sex Wt.Mean    Wt.SD
1 adult female    97.5 3.535534
2 adult   male    90.0 0.000000
3 young female    80.0 0.000000
4 young   male    75.0 0.000000
```

Answer (score 5):

Reshape lets you pass 2 functions; reshape2 does not.

```
library(reshape)
my.Data = read.table(text = "
  animal    age     sex  weight
       1  adult  female     100
       2  young    male      75
       3  adult    male      90
       4  adult  female      95
       5  young  female      80
", sep = "", header = TRUE)
my.Data[,1]<- NULL
(a1<-  melt(my.Data, id=c("age", "sex"), measured=c("weight")))
(cast(a1, age + sex ~ variable, c(mean, sd), fill=NA))

#     age    sex weight_mean weight_sd
# 1 adult female        97.5  3.535534
# 2 adult   male        90.0        NA
# 3 young female        80.0        NA
# 4 young   male        75.0        NA
```

I owe this to @Ramnath, who noted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182888/complicated-reshaping/15187498#15187498) just yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

The function `aggregate_multiple_fun` in the `SSBtools` package is a wrapper to `aggregate` that allows multiple functions and functions of several variables. In this case two possibilities are:

```
library(SSBtools)
my.Data = read.table(text = "
  animal    age     sex  weight
       1  adult  female     100
       2  young    male      75
       3  adult    male      90
       4  adult  female      95
       5  young  female      80
", sep = "", header = TRUE)


aggregate_multiple_fun(my.Data, my.Data[c("age", "sex")], 
                       vars = c(mean = "weight", sd = "weight"))

#     age    sex weight_mean weight_sd
# 1 adult female        97.5  3.535534
# 2 young female        80.0        NA
# 3 adult   male        90.0        NA
# 4 young   male        75.0        NA

aggregate_multiple_fun(my.Data, my.Data[c("age", "sex")], 
                       vars = "weight", fun = c("mean", "sd"))

#     age    sex mean       sd
# 1 adult female 97.5 3.535534
# 2 young female 80.0       NA
# 3 adult   male 90.0       NA
# 4 young   male 75.0       NA
```