# using of multiple functions using apply family, aggregation, with etc

Tags: r

I have checked and I found several questions related to this questions [multiple functions in a single tapply or aggregate statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215076/multiple-functions-in-a-single-tapply-or-aggregate-statement?rq=1)
[R Grouping functions: sapply vs. lapply vs. apply. vs. tapply vs. by vs. aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega?rq=1)

Actually I want to know what is the best way to use multiple functions in one of the above mentioned algorithms.

I try to give an example

```
# make a simple matrix 
df <- matrix(data=rnorm(10), 10, 5)

# make a function which calculate several properties 
several <- function(x) {
      c(min = min(x), mean = mean(x), max = max(x), median =median(x), sum=sum(x))
   }

# use one of the apply family 
apply(df,2, several)
```

how would you do that ? is there any other way to make it easier or more practical ?

Comment: Your `df` is `matrix` so, `apply` works okay.  If you need to work with `lapply`, convert the dataset to `data.frame`  Other option would be to use `summarise_each` from `dplyr`

Comment: @akrun you can make an example if you want to !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`each` in package `plyr` does the trick for you too:

```
library(plyr)
df <- matrix(data=rnorm(50), 10, 5)
aaply(df, 2, each(min, mean, max, median, sum))
```

If you want another input/output format, you can play with the different functions from `dplyr`.