# Applying multiple function via sapply

Tags: r, function, apply, gsub, sapply

I'm trying to replicate solution on applying multiple functions in `sapply` posted on [R-Bloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/applying-multiple-functions-to-data-frame/) but I can't get it to work in the desired manner. I'm working with a simple data set, similar to the one generated below:

```
require(datasets)
crs_mat <- cor(mtcars)

# Triangle function
get_upper_tri <- function(cormat){
  cormat[lower.tri(cormat)] <- NA
  return(cormat)
}

require(reshape2)
crs_mat <- melt(get_upper_tri(crs_mat))
```

I would like to replace some text values across columns *Var1* and *Var2*. The **erroneous** syntax below illustrates what I am trying to achieve:

```
crs_mat[,1:2] <- sapply(crs_mat[,1:2], function(x) {
 # Replace first phrase
 gsub("mpg","MPG",x), 
 # Replace second phrase
  gsub("gear", "GeArr",x)
 # Ideally, perform other changes
})
```

Naturally, the code is not syntactically correct and fails. To summarise, I would like to do the following:

1. Go through all the values in first two columns *(Var1 and Var2)* and perform simple replacements via `gsub`.
2. Ideally, I would like to avoid defining a separate function, as discussed in the [linked](http://www.r-bloggers.com/applying-multiple-functions-to-data-frame/) post and keep everything *within* the `sapply` syntax
3. I don't want a nested loop

---

I had a look at the broadly similar subject discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15215131/1655567) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7406550/1655567) but, if possible, I would like to avoid making use of `plyr`. I'm also interested in replacing the column values not in creating new columns and I would like to avoid specifying any column names. While working with my existing data frame it is more convenient for me to use column numbers.

## Edit

Following very useful comments, what I'm trying to achieve can be summarised in the solution below:

```
fun.clean.columns <- function(x, str_width = 15) {
  # Make character
  x <- as.character(x)
  # Replace various phrases
  x <- gsub("perc85","something else", x)
  x <- gsub("again", x)
  x <- gsub("more","even more", x)
  x <- gsub("abc","ohmg", x)
  # Clean spaces
  x <- trimws(x)
  # Wrap strings
  x <- str_wrap(x, width = str_width)
  # Return object
  return(x)
}
mean_data[,1:2] <- sapply(mean_data[,1:2], fun.clean.columns)
```

I don't need this function in my `global.env` so I can run `rm` after this but even nicer solution would involve *squeezing* this within the `apply` syntax.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the other changes you want to do? How many replacements do you have?

Comment: @Heroka, thanks for showing the interest. Let's assume that I'm willing to make 10 replacements and other cosmetic changes like applying `trimws`. On principle, `gsub` is enough for me but I want to be able to apply various iterations of the `gsub` commands to the columns I decide to pass via `sapply`.

Comment: The main problem you have, is that you're not assigning anything, so no changes are made.

Comment: If you are replacing multiple entries, why not use `mgsub` from `library(qdap)`

Comment: @Heroka I know, as indicated, the code is wrong but it conveys what I am trying to achieve. In simple words I want to apply multiple operations to the list of columns without *within* the `sapply`. In effect, it's a syntax problem. I could write a function and pass it to `sapply` but I don't want to.

Comment: @Konrad see my answer, it's very close to what you wrote but syntactically correct and everything is within sapply.

Comment: @akrun `mgsub` would work, but I'm interested in solving the problem via `sapply`. There is no specific reason for that, I just want to learn more about `sapply`.

Comment: @Konrad I would not use `sapply` as the structure gets mangled.  The output of `sapply` is a `matrix` for list of equal lengths.  The main point of my code is to reduce the number of `gsub` calls.

Comment: Just to give an example `df1 <- data.frame(V1= LETTERS[1:5], V2= LETTERS[3:7]);sapply(df1, relevel, ref='D'); lapply(df1, relevel, ref='D')`.  Even if you are assigning to the dataset i.e. `df1[] <- sapply(df1, ..` The class gets changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `mgsub` from `library(qdap)` to replace multiple patterns.  Here, I am looping the first and second column using `lapply` and assign the results back to the `crs_mat[,1:2]`.  Note that I am using `lapply` instead of `sapply` as `lapply` keeps the structure intact

```
library(qdap)
crs_mat[,1:2] <- lapply(crs_mat[,1:2], mgsub, 
   pattern=c('mpg', 'gear'), replacement=c('MPG', 'GeArr'))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your contribution. The solution would definitely work in case of `gsub`, I'm mostly interested in expanding `sapply` syntax as I would like to capitalise on the available flexibility. For example I may have to apply `gsub` 5 times, after `trimws` and finally `toupper` or something on those lines.

Comment: @Konrad I guess you have looked at the example posted showing `lapply` vs `sapply`

Comment: I did, but it's not clear to me whether it would be possible to draft an dequate syntax. I understand that I could define a new function `my_problematic_strings <- function(string_var) { # All the stuff I want to do }` and then pass it: `sapply(dta_with_columns, function(x) my_problematic_strings)`. Ideally, I wouldn't like to define this function as it will "sit" in a global environment for no reason.

Comment: @Konrad I didn't understand how the `sapply` will be a better option than `lapply` based on what you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a start of a solution for you, I think you're capable of extending it yourself. There's probably more elegant approaches available, but I don't see them atm.

```
crs_mat[,1:2] <- sapply(crs_mat[,1:2], function(x) {
  # Replace first phrase
  step1 <- gsub("mpg","MPG",x)
  # Replace second phrase. Note that this operates on a modified dataframe. 
  step2 <- gsub("gear", "GeArr",step1)
  # Ideally, perform other changes
  return(step2)

  #or one nested line, not practical if more needs to be done
  #return(gsub("gear", "GeArr",gsub("mpg","MPG",x)))
})
```